# Find and classify the spectrum of multiplication operator on $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

We define an operator $T$ on $X=L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ as $T(f)(x)=min(2x,1)f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

I'd like to find the spectrum of $T$. I computed the operator norm, which is $||T||=1$, so we know that $\sigma(T) \subset [-1,1]$. More specifically, I'd like to find the point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)$, i.e. all the $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda Id_X-T$ is not injective.

Let's assume the opposite, meaning that there exists a non-zero function $f$ in $X$ such that
$(\lambda Id_X-T)f(x)=0$. ,  i.e. $\lambda=min(2x,1)$

I think the correct answer is $\sigma_p(T)={1}$, but I don't understand why. My main issue is that $1$ does not seem to be in $\sigma_p(T)$ for $x \in (1/2,1]$, as we'd have $min(2x,1)=1 =\lambda$ (in the equality in the previous paragraph) and thus $(\lambda Id_X-T)$ would be injective. There must be something I'm not understanding correctly...

Finally, how does one find the continuous and residual spectrum? What is the procedure (a lot of detail would be very apprectiated)?

Comment: It has to be $0=(\lambda - \text{min}(2x,1))f(x)$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$. So the only possible value for $\lambda$ is $1$ and as an eigenfunction for example $f = 1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$. $\lambda$ is constant.

Comment: On general the spectrum of $Tf=gf$ where $g$ is continuous coincides with the range of $g.$ If $g$ is constant on an interval the value of $g$ on this interval is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @psl2Z okay, so for $\lambda=1, 0=(\lambda -min(2x,1))f(x)$ is true outside of $[0,1/2)$, but that set is not of Lebesgue measure $0$, so I don't understand how that equality is true almost everywhere

Comment: If you take $f$ like in my comment above we have $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ and therefore $0 = (\lambda-\text{min}(2x,1))f(x)$ in $[0, \frac{1}{2})$. For $x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$ it is $f(x) = 1$ but it is also $\text{min}(2x,1) = 1$ and therefore $0 = \lambda - \text{min}(2x,1) $. So, $0 = (\lambda-\text{min}(2x,1))f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ but $f \neq 0$.

Comment: @psl2Z okay, I got it, thanks!